# JQuery Megamenu issues: Expands all instances when one is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code that displays a mega menu. I wanted to create several instances of this menu, so that I can use it at several pages on my web page. I tried doing so by pasting the code in the JS file several times, and renaming the classes. Then in the CSS, I pasted the same file names.
The code seems to work, now that I have multiple instances of the same menu on the same page. However, now what happens is that on the lower resolutions, when I expand one menu, all menus get expanded.

How can I isolate all the different instances of this mega menu? Any help will be appreciated. I am adding the code for the files I changed. Will try to see if I can add the original code (i.e. the orignal code for one menu)

```js
/*global $ */
$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

    $('.menu-autos > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
    //Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI


    $('.menu-autos > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
    //Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu (thanks Luka Kladaric)

    $(".menu-autos > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\">Navigation</a>");

    //Adds menu-mobile class (for mobile toggle menu) before the normal menu
    //Mobile menu is hidden if width is more then 959px, but normal menu is displayed
    //Normal menu is hidden if width is below 959px, and jquery adds mobile menu
    //Done this way so it can be used with wordpress without any trouble

    $(".menu-autos > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 767) {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

    $(".menu-autos > ul > li").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
            $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        }
    });
    //If width is less or equal to 943px dropdowns are displayed on click (thanks Aman Jain from stackoverflow)

    $(".menu-mobile").click(function (e) {
        $(".menu-autos > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //when clicked on mobile-menu, normal menu is shown as a list, classic rwd menu story (thanks mwl from stackoverflow)

});


/* =============================================================  mobiles ====================================== */

$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

    $('.menu-phones > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
    //Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI


    $('.menu-phones > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
    //Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu 
 
    $(".menu-phones > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\">Navigation</a>");

    //Adds menu-mobile class (for mobile toggle menu) before the normal menu
    //Mobile menu is hidden if width is more then 959px, but normal menu is displayed
    //Normal menu is hidden if width is below 959px, and jquery adds mobile menu
    //Done this way so it can be used with wordpress without any trouble

    $(".menu-phones > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 767) {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

    $(".menu-phones > ul > li").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
            $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        }
    });
    //If width is less or equal to 943px dropdowns are displayed on click (thanks Aman Jain from stackoverflow)

    $(".menu-mobile").click(function (e) {
        $(".menu-phones > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //when clicked on mobile-menu, normal menu is shown as a list, classic rwd menu story (thanks mwl from stackoverflow)

});


/* =============================================================  computing ====================================== */

$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

    $('.menu-computing > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
    //Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI


    $('.menu-computing > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
    //Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu (thanks Luka Kladaric)

    $(".menu-computing > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\">Navigation</a>");

    //Adds menu-mobile class (for mobile toggle menu) before the normal menu
    //Mobile menu is hidden if width is more then 959px, but normal menu is displayed
    //Normal menu is hidden if width is below 959px, and jquery adds mobile menu
    //Done this way so it can be used with wordpress without any trouble

    $(".menu-computing > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 767) {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

    $(".menu-computing > ul > li").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
            $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        }
    });
    //If width is less or equal to 943px dropdowns are displayed on click (thanks Aman Jain from stackoverflow)

    $(".menu-mobile").click(function (e) {
        $(".menu-computing > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //when clicked on mobile-menu, normal menu is shown as a list, classic rwd menu story (thanks mwl from stackoverflow)

});// JavaScript Document




/* =============================================================  electronics ====================================== */

$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

    $('.menu-electronics > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
    //Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI


    $('.menu-electronics > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
    //Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu (thanks Luka Kladaric)

    $(".menu-electronics > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\">Navigation</a>");

    //Adds menu-mobile class (for mobile toggle menu) before the normal menu
    //Mobile menu is hidden if width is more then 959px, but normal menu is displayed
    //Normal menu is hidden if width is below 959px, and jquery adds mobile menu
    //Done this way so it can be used with wordpress without any trouble

    $(".menu-electronics > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 767) {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

    $(".menu-electronics > ul > li").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
            $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        }
    });
    //If width is less or equal to 943px dropdowns are displayed on click (thanks Aman Jain from stackoverflow)

    $(".menu-mobile").click(function (e) {
        $(".menu-electronics > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //when clicked on mobile-menu, normal menu is shown as a list, classic rwd menu story (thanks mwl from stackoverflow)

});// JavaScript Document




/* =============================================================  business ====================================== */

$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

    $('.menu-business > ul > li:has( > ul)').addClass('menu-dropdown-icon');
    //Checks if li has sub (ul) and adds class for toggle icon - just an UI


    $('.menu-business > ul > li > ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('normal-sub');
    //Checks if drodown menu's li elements have anothere level (ul), if not the dropdown is shown as regular dropdown, not a mega menu (thanks Luka Kladaric)

    $(".menu-business > ul").before("<a href=\"#\" class=\"menu-mobile\">Navigation</a>");

    //Adds menu-mobile class (for mobile toggle menu) before the normal menu
    //Mobile menu is hidden if width is more then 959px, but normal menu is displayed
    //Normal menu is hidden if width is below 959px, and jquery adds mobile menu
    //Done this way so it can be used with wordpress without any trouble

    $(".menu-business > ul > li").hover(function (e) {
        if ($(window).width() > 767) {
            $(this).children("ul").stop(true, false).fadeToggle(150);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    //If width is more than 943px dropdowns are displayed on hover

    $(".menu-business > ul > li").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
            $(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(150);
        }
    });
    //If width is less or equal to 943px dropdowns are displayed on click (thanks Aman Jain from stackoverflow)

    $(".menu-mobile").click(function (e) {
        $(".menu-business > ul").toggleClass('show-on-mobile');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    //when clicked on mobile-menu, normal menu is shown as a list, classic rwd menu story (thanks mwl from stackoverflow)

});// JavaScript Document
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    color: #333;
}

.description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}


/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
megamenu.js STYLE STARTS HERE
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */


/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Screen style's
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.menu-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}

.menu-mobile {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
}

.menu-mobile:after {
    content: "+";
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-25%);
    transform: translateY(-25%);
}

.menu-dropdown-icon:before {
    content: "+";
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    padding: 1.5em 2em;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

.menu-autos > ul, .menu-phones > ul, .menu-electronics > ul, .menu-business > ul, .menu-computing > ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    /* IF .menu position=relative -> ul = container width, ELSE ul = 100% width */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-autos > ul:before,
.menu-autos > ul:after, .menu-phones > ul:before,
.menu-phones > ul:after, .menu-electronics > ul:before,
.menu-electronics > ul:after, .menu-business > ul:before,
.menu-business > ul:after, .menu-computing > ul:before,
.menu-computing > ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.menu-autos > ul:after, .menu-phones > ul:after, .menu-electronics > ul:after, .menu-business > ul:after, .menu-computing > ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li, .menu-phones > ul > li, .menu-electronics > ul > li, .menu-business > ul > li, .menu-computing > ul > li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li a, .menu-phones > ul > li a, .menu-business > ul > li a, .menu-electronics > ul > li a, .menu-computing > ul > li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1.5em 1.25em;
    display: block;
 
}

.menu-autos > ul > li:hover, .menu-phones > ul > li:hover, .menu-business > ul > li:hover, .menu-electronics > ul > li:hover, .menu-computing > ul > li:hover {
    border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul, .menu-business > ul > li > ul, .menu-computing> ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu-autos > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu-phones > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu-electronics > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-business > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu-business > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu-computing > ul > li > ul:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-business > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li , .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li , .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    background: none;
    float: left;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li a, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li a , .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li a , .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li a, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li a {
    color: #777;
    padding: .2em 0;
    width: 95%;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li > ul, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li > ul, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li > ul, .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li > ul, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu-business > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li > ul:before,
.menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li > ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: .8em;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a , .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a , .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li a {
    border: 0;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul.normal-sub, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul.normal-sub, .menu-business > ul > li > ul.normal-sub, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul.normal-sub, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul.normal-sub {
    width: 300px;
    left: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li, .menu-business > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-autos > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li a, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li a, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li a, .menu-business > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li a , .menu-computing > ul > li > ul.normal-sub > li a {
    border: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
}


/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
Mobile style's
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .menu-container {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .menu-mobile {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-dropdown-icon:before {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-autos > ul, .menu-phones > ul, .menu-electronics > ul, .menu-business > ul, .menu-computing > ul {
        display: none;
    }
    .menu-autos > ul > li, .menu-phones > ul > li, .menu-electronics > ul > li, .menu-business > ul > li, .menu-computing > ul > li {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-autos > ul > li a, .menu-phones > ul > li a, .menu-electronics > ul > li a, .menu-business > ul > li a , .menu-computing > ul > li a {
        padding: 1.5em;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    .menu-autos > ul > li > ul, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul, .menu-business > ul > li > ul, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul {
        position: relative;
    }
    .menu-autos > ul > li > ul.normal-sub, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul.normal-sub , .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul.normal-sub , .menu-business > ul > li > ul.normal-sub, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul.normal-sub {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li:first-child, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li:first-child, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li:first-child, .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li:first-child, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li:first-child {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li > ul, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li > ul, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li > ul, .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li > ul, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
        position: relative;
    }
    .menu-autos > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-phones > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-electronics > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-business > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li, .menu-computing > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
        float: none;
    }
    .menu-autos .show-on-mobile, .menu-phones .show-on-mobile, .menu-electronics .show-on-mobile, .menu-business .show-on-mobile, .menu-computing .show-on-mobile {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have 5 categories for which I need 5 instances of this menu. Even  after isolation on mobile resolution , that is 767 px, when In try to expand  one category, it expands all categories.

Comment: I could not add the HTML because it seemed to exceed StackOverflow's character limit in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste of your javascript with separate CSS classes is not maintainable or an efficient use of your time. Lets say you change the functionality of the menu.. You will need to duplicate those changes across each menu category.

A better solution is to create a plugin out of this code, which you can use on as many menus as you want. I would suggest reading through [Jquery - How to Create a basic plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) as a start.

Comment: I understand, and I thank you for sharing this link, I''ll read it as soon as I can. But for now, i'm in the middle of a time-sensitive project. And i need this functionality on the page, which is why I pasted. 
Do you see any errors in the code here?